# What is meant by: "He felt something much more keenly"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is meant by: "He felt something much more keenly"?

Context(From Anne of Avonlea by L.M.Montgomery):

"Anne stood Morley on the platform for an hour and—which Morley *felt
much more keenly*—confiscated his crickets."

Comment: Consider how you'd feel if the keen edge of a knife blade were pressing harder and and harder against your skin.

Comment: The question is rather confusing as you cannot "feel keenly". You can only "feel *something* keenly". In this case *which* is the object of the verb and it refers to the loss of the crickets. I have edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @DavidRobinson -- ??? "Keenly" is an adverb.  "Felt" is a verb.  "Joe felt keenly the hatred of Sam."

Comment: Yes, @hotlicks, your example makes the point. This verb needs an object in almost all contexts. You have supplied one in your example but the original question made it sound like the question was about an intransitive use of *felt*. It is usual to provide *something* or some other suitable placeholder object when generalising examples of transitive verbs.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't read the whole piece, but from what little I read, I assume Anne to be a teacher, who, just prior to this quote, witnessed the "trained crickets" belonging to Morley, whom I assume to be a pupil.

I interpret it to mean she "stood him on the platform" as a form of punishment and took his crickets, a punishment that hurt him more than the platform. That is, he wasn't much bothered by the first punishment, but the second was more intensely *punishing*.

As [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/keenly) defines **keenly**,

> 2b of emotion or feeling: INTENSE